# Capitalizing words in an array, Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, capitalize

I'm going through App Academy's Ruby Prep questions, and I want to know why this solution works. It appears that the words array is never altered and yet the method works. Is this a glitch in the matrix, or is it right under my nose?

```
def capitalize_words(string)
  words = string.split(" ")

  idx = 0
  while idx < words.length
    word = words[idx]
    word[0] = word[0].upcase
    idx += 1
  end

  return words.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: Posted, sorry this is my first post and formatting took a moment. @August

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) is a mutating operation. To illustrate using a concise, contained excerpt from your code:

```
word = "foo"
word[0] = word[0].upcase  # <-- verbatim from your code
word #=> "Foo"
```

`word` is still the same exact object contained in the array `words` (arrays simply contain references to objects, not the data within them), but it has been *mutated* in-place. It’s generally best to avoid mutations whenever possible as it makes it non-obvious what is happening (as you can see).

Your code could also be more concisely written using [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-map) & [`capitalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-capitalize) (and without any mutations):

```
string.split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

Comment: Forget it, I can't put what I'm trying to say in this comment. -_-

Answer (score 3):

The method works because `word` contains a reference to the array position. So when you assign:

```
word = words[idx]
```

You're just using `word` as a shorthand to operate on that array element, which gets modified by:

```
word[0] = word[0].upcase
```

--

Also, if you'd like to come back to this answer after learning some Ruby, here's a simplified version of the method:

```
def capitalize_words(string)
  string.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
end
```

Comment: That's... really weird. I would think that I would have to set words[idx] = word. Is this a ruby-specific thing or what? Is there a name for this so that I can study it a little more?

Comment: @Styx_ It’s called *mutation*. As stated in my answer, Arrays simply contain references to objects, so when you mutate the object, it “changes” everywhere there’s a reference to it. If you call `freeeze` on an object in Ruby it cannot be mutated. Almost every language (unfortunately) is ridden with mutation, save [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure).

Answer (score 0):

`word = word[idx]` creates a copy of your data.  It will then modify that copy instead of the words in the original array.

Simple solution would be:

```
def capitalize_words(string)
  words = string.split(" ")

  idx = 0
  while idx < words.length
    words[idx][0] = words[idx][0].upcase
    idx += 1
  end

  return words.join(" ")
end
```